# Python pygal code - World mapping

Tags: python, pygal, world-map

Could you please help me with this code:

```
import pygal
from pygal.maps.world import World
worldmap_chart = pygal.maps.world.World()
worldmap_chart.title = 'Some countries'
worldmap_chart.render()
```

I use Spyder. Python 3.6 .The problem is that the map does not show up on the IPython console, and also on the second line of the code, I get yellow triangle/note that says:

> 'pygal.maps.world.World' imported but unused.

Maybe this is the reason why the map does not show up.

Otherwise, if it helps, in the IPython console I get only this:

> runfile('C:/Users/Nikki/.spyder-py3/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/Users/Nikki/.spyder-py3')

Could you please help me to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not personnaly use Spyder, but the third line of your code seems to be wrong,
you should try this :

```
import pygal
from pygal.maps.world import World
worldmap_chart = World()
worldmap_chart.title = 'Some countries'
worldmap_chart.render()
```

Or better :

```
import pygal
worldmap_chart = pygal.maps.world.World()
worldmap_chart.title = 'Some countries'
worldmap_chart.render()
```

Depends on what you need to use in `pygal` or `pygal.maps.world`.

Edit : 
I tried to render, but nothing appears, one trick is to render in browser which works for me as follow :

```
import pygal

worldmap_chart = pygal.maps.world.World()
worldmap_chart.title = 'Some countries'
worldmap_chart.force_uri_protocol= "http"
worldmap_chart.add('North America',{'ca': 84949494949,'mx': 494794164,'us': 99794616})
worldmap_chart.render_in_browser()
```

Comment: Hi @Fou, thank you for giving attention to my problem. I appreciate it. I tried with the first code, but it says again 'pygal imported but not used'.  However, when I use the second code, I don't get any remarks from Spyder. It seems ok, but somehow I still don't get any map in the IPython console. I just get runfile('C:/Users/Nikki/.spyder-py3/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/Users/Nikki/.spyder-py3')   I don't understand what could be the reason the map not to show up

Comment: I edited the answer to render in a browser which works for me

Comment: Hi Fou. Thanks so much. I tried your code and indeed it opens up when I try in Chrome. Does it mean that I should use some different Python environment instead of Spyder?

Comment: I don't think so, I also tried the render function with Ipython and it only returns a string and doesn't display anything..
You can also try the render_to_png() function which work for me